# ApacheCommons/lang/StringUtils not found

Tags: java, maven, jboss

As known, the `JBoss AS 7.0.0` provides some `apache-commons` dependencies out of the box. They are located in the

```
$JBOSS_HOME$\modules\org\apache\commons\lang\main
```

So, I tried to use these provided dependencies by declaring the following dependency in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>${commons.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And when I tried to use of of its classes I got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    com.badmitrii.EmployeeListController.getEmployees(EmployeeListController.java:39)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Of course, if I replace the `scope` tag with `compile` it'll be work fine. But what's wrong with the usage of the library embedded into the server? Maybe additional configuration needed?

Comment: What is your `commons.version`? Does it match the supplied one?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, my commons version is exactly the same as what was supplied. It's 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding org.apache.commons.lang in the Dependencies section of your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.

I think the problem is that you are not declaring the dependency, so JBoss is not loading the class for you..

Hope it helps!

EDIT: You can set this up through maven using maven-war-plugin or maven-ear-plugin. Here's an example:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>

        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>org.apache.commons.lang</Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: BTW, is it possible to write such a dependecies automatically via maven?

Comment: You are very welcome! glad it helped.. yes, you can write it with maven, I updated my answer..